# generate a list depending on list length

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing tuples.
I want to search through that list by checking all first items of the tuples.
If I have only one result I want to return a list with index 0 of the search result.
If results > 1 I want to return a list with index 1 of the search results.

I was trying to do this with generators but failed. I have now come up with following, but I feel this could be better.. Anyone some suggestions ?

```
a = [("ab", 2), ("ac", 3), ("bd", 3)]

def returner(keyword):
    def firstitem(_a):
        list1.append(_a[0])
        list2.append(_a[1])

    def otheritems(_a):
        list2.append(_a[1])

    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    append = firstitem
    for _a in a:
        if _a[0].startswith(keyword):
            append(_a)
            append = otheritems
    return list2 if len(list2) > 1 else list1
```

`returner("a")` would result in `[2,3]` (index 0 of both tuples starting with one)

`returner("b")` would result in `["bd"]` (index 1 of tuple 3 as result length is only one)

Comment: Can you provide an example of an input and a desired output ? it is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. What is result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not able to figure out the reason for a peculiar function like this, but a simpler equivalent is:

```
def returner2(keyword):
    rv=[]
    first_match=None
    for _a in a:
        if _a[0].startswith(keyword):
            if first_match is None:
                first_match=_a[0]
            rv.append(_a[1])

    if len(rv)==1:
        return [first_match]
    else:
        return rv
```

Comment: Thanks.Edited my original post with examples of output. Your equivalent is not equivalent.

Comment: sorry, but I can't see how its different. This function returns the same results for the inputs you have provided in your post

Comment: Alright. Changed my code. It is now closer to what I intend to do.

Comment: Got it, I guess you needed the first match and not the keyword, modified my method to handle this